# Victim of accidental murder's wife falling to Yibum?

Tags: mistakes, yibbum-chalitza-levirate, city-of-refuge

Assuming the following is in a case where Yibum is practiced:

If someone accidentally killed his married brother who has no children, does the deceased brother's wife fall to Yibum if the killer wants to marry her via Yibum?

And if so, how is it Halachically fair that the woman must live with her husband's killer in Galus?

Furthermore, if there's no one else who can be Goel HaDam, can she be the one to avenge him?

Comment: Murder is discussed already here https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/84779/759 Not sure what you mean by "halachically fair". If she doesn't want to marry him there she can request chalitza.

Comment: Is a wife/widow ever a goelet hadam?